How common is it for national finances to be secured by the head of the central bank knowing the "password"?
It is reported that the governor of the Libyan central bank Sadiq al-Kabir was recently sacked, and has "secret codes" that are required to make payments.

There was no sign on Tuesday that the UN-backed institutions in the west of Libya, led by Abdul Hamid Dbeibah, were backing down over their dismissal of the bank’s governor of the past 20 years and installation of a new leadership.
Abdel Fattah Ghaffar, the new interim deputy governor appointed by the Tripoli-based government, ... called on Kabir to hand over the secret codes that would make payments possible

While I am sure this is more like a cryptocurrency wallet than a consumers banking password, it surprises me somewhat.
How common is it globally for the control over a national bank to be exercised by the possession of "secrets" like this?

My guess it's related to their USD deposits (said to be $27B) which are almost certainly held by a US bank. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangladesh_Bank_robbery where the theives managed to "gain access to the bank's credentials for payment transfers".

This is the level of sophistication in financial security typical in the U.S. of small rural towns.

"I am sure this is more like a cryptocurrency wallet than a consumers banking password" ─ Why are you sure of that? Nations have accounts with foreign banks, but I have not heard of any nation having national holdings of cryptocurrency.

@kaya3 Mostly because passwords are really bad ways to secure IT access.  I could have said something like DIDs or TOTP authenticator keys but that may have been less well understood.

This is not a question about politics. It is a question about entities happen to secure access to important systems. Just because the entities happen to be political entities does not turn it into a question about politics.

@User65535 Nobody said only a password is required, the problem is that the password is required. And other authentication methods based on some other secret such as a private key, are vulnerable to the same issue of "the previous guy kept it for himself and won't give the secret to the new guy".

@User65535 Most financial institutions use 2FA, and a password is usually the first factor. A common 2nd factor is sending a code to a cellphone or email address, so they'd need his phone (just long enough to change the phone number associated with the account).
